# Find and Replace On Page Text Strings With Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'd like to find and replace specific text strings within an element across multiple URLS.

The element:

```
<div class="text-row"><p></p></div>
```

Within the p tags the text strings would be:

1."Endo" change to "Endodontist" 
2."MCD" change to "Lead Dentist"

How would I accomplish that using Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript you can look for the elements that match by class/id and just edit them.

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('text-row')){
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('text-row');
    for(var k = 0;k < elems.length;k++){
        var text = elems[k].innerText;
        if(text.indexOf('Endo') != -1){
            text.replace('Endo','Endodontist');
            elems[k].innerText = text;
        }
    }
}
```